# replace words in a string with respect to words in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a string:

```
str = 'i have a banana and an apple'
```

i also have a dataframe

```
name    new_name
have     had
bed      eat
banana   lime
```

i want to replace words in string if that words exists in pandas df.

for eg( for my str= the output should be.

```
'i had a lime and an apple'
```

i am tryng to define a function

```
def replace(df,string):
    L = []
    for i in string:
        new_word = df[[new_name]].loc[df.name==i].item()
        if not new_word:
             new_word = i
    L.append(new_word)
    result_str = ' '.join(map(str, L))
    return result_str
```

But this seems very lenghty, is there a better way(time efficient) to get such output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with parameter `regex=True`:

```
a = 'i have a banana and an apple'

b = pd.Series(a).replace(df.set_index('name')['new_name'], regex=True)[0]
print (b)
i had a lime and an apple
```

Another solution:

```
a = 'i have a banana and an apple'

import re
d = df.set_index('name')['new_name'].to_dict()
p = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(d.keys()) + r')\b')
b = p.sub(lambda x: d[x.group()], a)
print (b)
i had a lime and an apple
```

**Timings**:

```
a = 'i have a banana and an apple' * 1000

In [205]: %%timeit
     ...: import re
     ...: d = df.set_index('name')['new_name'].to_dict()
     ...: p = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(d.keys()) + r')\b')
     ...: b = p.sub(lambda x: d[x.group()], a)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.52 ms per loop

In [206]: %%timeit
     ...: pd.Series(a).replace(df.set_index('name')['new_name'], regex=True)[0]
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.43 ms per loop


In [208]: %%timeit
     ...: m = df.set_index('name').new_name
     ...: 
     ...: pd.Series(a.split()).replace(m).str.cat(sep=' ')
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.11 ms per loop


In [211]: %%timeit
     ...: m = df.set_index('name').new_name.to_dict()
     ...: p = r'\b{}\b'.format(df.name.str.cat(sep='|'))
     ...: 
     ...: re.sub(p, lambda x: m.get(x.group()), a)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.91 ms per loop
```

---

```
a = 'i have a banana and an apple' * 10000

In [213]: %%timeit
     ...: import re
     ...: d = df.set_index('name')['new_name'].to_dict()
     ...: p = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(d.keys()) + r')\b')
     ...: b = p.sub(lambda x: d[x.group()], a)
     ...: 
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 19.8 ms per loop

In [214]: %%timeit
     ...: pd.Series(a).replace(df.set_index('name')['new_name'], regex=True)[0]
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.1 ms per loop

In [215]: %%timeit
     ...: m = df.set_index('name').new_name
     ...: 
     ...: pd.Series(a.split()).replace(m).str.cat(sep=' ')
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 26.3 ms per loop

In [216]: %%timeit
     ...: m = df.set_index('name').new_name.to_dict()
     ...: p = r'\b{}\b'.format(df.name.str.cat(sep='|'))
     ...: 
     ...: re.sub(p, lambda x: m.get(x.group()), a)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 22.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: @jezrael can you %timeit and see which is more time efficient?
 coz, i'll be doing this for around 1000-2000 strings

Comment: I think last solution should be the fastest.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ says that the first one will be faster , check his comment

Comment: @SRingne - I add timings, but it depends of length of DatyaFrame, so the best test in your data.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

1. Split your string on the natural delimiter (space)
2. Call `pd.Series.replace`, and pass `new_name` as an argument
3. Combine the cells in the series with `str.cat`/`str.join`

```
m = df.set_index('name').new_name

pd.Series(string.split()).replace(m).str.cat(sep=' ')
'i had a lime and an apple'
```

Where `string` is your original string. Don't use `str` to define variables, that hides the builtin class with the same name.

Alternatively, calling `str.join` should be faster than `str.cat` -

```
' '.join(pd.Series(string.split()).replace(m).tolist())
'i had a lime and an apple'
```

I'll be using this method of joining strings in Series from now one, you'll also see it in the forthcoming option.

---

**Option 2**
You can skip pandas, and instead use `re.sub`:

```
import re

m = df.set_index('name').new_name.to_dict()
p = r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(df.name.tolist()))

re.sub(p, lambda x: m.get(x.group()), string)
'i had a lime and an apple'
```

---

**Performance**

```
string = 'i have a banana and an apple ' * 10000
```

```
# Series-`replacement

%%timeit
m = df.set_index('name').new_name
' '.join(pd.Series(string.split()).replace(m).tolist())

100 loops, best of 3: 20.3 ms per loop
```

```
# `re`gex replacement

%%timeit
m = df.set_index('name').new_name.to_dict()
p = r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(df.name.tolist()))
re.sub(p, lambda x: m.get(x.group()), string)

10 loops, best of 3: 30.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: Can you %timeit and see which is more time efficient?

Comment: @SRingne Sure, I can. Also, regex replacement in general is slow, unfortunately. With a non-regex replacement, you can probably gain something, but the moment you've invoked the regex parser, you've implicitly agreed to lose performance. The second option in both our answers suffers this problem, but there is no overhead in Pandas, so that's a plus...

Comment: OTOH, my first answer does not use regex at all, so if you're interested, try that.

Comment: Thanks,i'll use the first one :) i was just wondering this because i have heard that dealing with series and dataframe is more costlier than dealing with lists and strings

Comment: @SRingne True, true. The best is to test it out, which I'll do. But I recommend you doing your own tests too because the performance _really_ depends on the data.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Sure!

Comment: @SRingne I've tuned my code and added some timings for the fastest versions of those options of mine.

Comment: @SRingne I'm not saying mine is the fastest between the two answerERs, but I'm saying my first option is the fastest of the two. In any case, I'd strongly suggest testing all options before deciding what to use in your code. Cheers.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - then why dont add my solutions to your timings? What is reason?

Comment: @COLDSPEED I've tested it , and found jezrael's first answer is fastest among all

Comment: @jezrael No reason, it's my answer and I just wanted to put my timings. I never said your answer is slow, if you read the comments. I also encouraged OP to test all solutions.

Comment: @COLDSPEED @ jezrael , both of you guys are amazing :)

Comment: @SRingne I've learned a lot answering your question, and I hope you learned a lot reading our answers. That's my primary goal here, not votes or accepts. Those are nice too, but they are secondary. Cheers, and good luck with the rest of your code :-)